# Converting input from int to double

Tags: c

Is there a way to convert actual input int to double. I dont want to get string values and use isDigit to check if it is double or int.

```
int main(void)
{

    // Initializing variables
    int a,b,c,res;

    // Getting input from user
    printf("Please enter the sides of triangle");

    printf("\nPlease enter side 1:");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("Please enter side 2:");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    printf("Please enter side 3:");
    scanf("%d",&c);


    // Calling function in order to print type of the triangle.
    checkTriangle(a,b,c);



}

// A function which decides the type of the triangle and print it
void checkTriangle(int s1, int s2,int s3)
{


    // Check the values whether it is triangle or not.
  if ((s1 + s2 > s3 && s1 +  s3 > s2 && s2 + s3 > s1) && (s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0))
     {
    // Deciding type of triangle according to given input.
      if (s1 == s2 && s2 == s3)
          printf("EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE");
      else if (s1 == s2 || s2 == s3 || s1 == s3)
          printf("ISOSCELES TRIANGLE\n");
      else
          printf("SCALENE TRIANGLE \n");
    }
     else
         printf("Triangle could not be formed.");


}
```

What i want to do wheni user type a double i wanna give a message that you can type double. Is there are way to do that without getting character input?

Comment: Where is this input coming from? What are you trying to do?

Comment: When user type double input it converts to int. How can i prevent this?

Comment: @MertMetin, Probably because it's expecting an int and it stops at the decimal because it's not a digit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `int` value that you wish to turn into a `double` simply use a cast:

```
int foo = 5;
double bar = (double) foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read input as a double, use:

```
double inputValue;
scanf("%lf", &inputValue);
```

The `"%lf"` tells `scanf` that the input is a double.

Comment: Actually, you'd want `%lf`. `%ld` is to read a `long`, which isn't floating point.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scanf("%d",&u)
or you can take input as int or char type and then typecast it to double.

Comment: yes, but can use getchar() or scanf("%c") for strictly taking char.